# Array of objects which have all the same properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, types

I was wondering, if it's possible to ensure with Angular 12 / Typescript, **that all objects within an array have the same properties, without declaring the properties explicitly** (should be generic).

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```js
// This should compile because all objects have the same properties
const correct = [
 {firstname: 'Jack', lastname: 'Sanders'}, 
 {firstname: 'Susanna', lastname: 'Marsaglia'},
 {firstname: 'Walter', lastname: 'Walker'}
]

// This shouldn't compile because some object have different properties
const wrong = [
 {firstname: 'Aline', lastname: 'Rose', phone: 'xxx-xxx-xx-xx'},
 {firstname: 'Daniel', email: 'dan@gmail.com'},
 {firstname: 'Louisa', email: 'louisa@icloud.com'}
]
```

I was able to create an Interface which only allows properties with type `string`, but I couldn't achieve the example above.

```js
export interface Data {
 [keys: string]: string
}
```

**Update (Use-Case)**

I need this check in a service which exports data. You should be able to pass an array of objects, which represent rows within a table.

For example:

```js
const data = [
 {firstname: 'Jack', lastname: 'Sanders'}, 
 {firstname: 'Susanna', lastname: 'Marsaglia'},
]

this.exportService.export(data);
```

This code would generate a file with a table like this:

| firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | Sanders |
| Susanna | Marsaglia |

The service should support any passed data, because it's used widely over our entire application. But to be sure that the service can export the data to a table, we need to ensure, that all passed objects have the same properties (e.g. columns).

Comment: You can't. If your object should have generic property names, they will have generic property names

Comment: I don't quite get it. You say it should be compilation check, but if you do not know the properties (implied by the generic property in interface) during the compilation time, how could it be checked during compilation time? In other words, is the data you need to check already available at compile time or is it only available at run time (like an API fetch)?

Comment: See my update. The properties are known at compilation time. But the service is used with so many different objects, that I want to prevent creating an interface for each possible combination of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well make your exportservice generic, ie something like this

```
class ExportService {

  public export<T>(data: T[]) {
     console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Or you can also just use `{[key:string]:string}` as element type in you export service

```
class ExportService {

  public export(data: {[key:string]:string}[]) {
     console.log(data);
  }
}
```

That doesn't hinder you from defining the type of your `data` correctly.

```
const data: { firstname: string, lastname: string}[] = [
  { firstname: "john", lastname: "foo"},
  { firstname: "jim", lastname: "bar"}
];

this.exportservice.export(data);
```

See also [this fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAsAKH2mgAcBXAIxHWngA9iB7RAFwEYAeAFQD4AKAEzDMwALmicA2gF0AlNkJFowBgDsIDEPAB0IBgHMBQsDIDcCgL74FZStTqMWAJkPCxWCQGt4ATxERmiKgqelJi-oHB5tJyuHiKSqrqmjr6LsZmcdCWBHjZ+JrM0DAAvNAq8ADucEhoGLymVngF0PysbtAAZiphAUF6ADTQIN1FvZHS0KUSWF1iAEQAVgwAFipzg8Pz-Azwc+ZSGc38ju0dqIj+KmAAtvA9EQNDkMxXt-d9UVKT0NNnFy83O7QRYrNYbZ6vIFzba7fYZAD08NQHWg3gYpGgpBUymutxUhWYy1QEEGhKQmAqqBAIGg5EwYBUNEQiCY+ERRwAzKcRuE+hseWM9J9vr8RiDVushmKYXtBlhOudLoD5ksJeClW9gTK4fgIFp7Ew2AJWA08HqDSxWAJHKbdfr6IbnK1TeaHU5raYgA)

Answer (score 1):

```
function sameKeys(input) {
  if (!input || input.length === 0) return;
  const keys = new Set(Object.keys(input[0]));

  return input.every((item) => Object.keys(item).every((key) => keys.has(key)));
}
```

If you want a compile time check, then doing a proper type definition makes sense have given in another answer. But that will only work if this data is hardcoded. if you are fetching it from backend it will not work as types are lost when the code is already build as javascript don't have types.

Comment: This is a runtime check and not at complie time

Comment: i guess the comments in code confuses here, what i understood from questions is that he want to check it at runtime.

Comment: `"this shouldn't compile"` made you think op wants a runtime check?

Comment: updated my answer to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
 {firstname: 'Jack', lastname: 'Sanders'}, 
 {firstname: 'Susanna', lastname: 'Marsaglia'},
 {firstname: 'Walter', lastname: 'Walker'}
]

const dataReference : Required<typeof data[number]>[] = data
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You should achieve this by interface as below

```
interface IStructure {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
  } 

const correct: Array<IStructure> = [
 {firstname: 'Jack', lastname: 'Sanders'}, 
 {firstname: 'Susanna', lastname: 'Marsaglia'},
 {firstname: 'Walter', lastname: 'Walker'}
];

//wrong will throw error
```

Comment: Op explicitly states he doesn't want to define an interface because the property names should be generic

Comment: @derpirscher that is not possible runtime.

Comment: Well, if something op is asking is not possible, then your answer should at least cover that and explain why you did something, op explicitly said he doesn't want.

Comment: @derpirscher  That is very well covered in other answer.